# sum of geometric series $\sum_{j=-N}^N e^{i \cdot j \cdot ξ \cdot λ}=\sin(N+{1\over 2}) \cdot (ξ \cdotλ)\over \sin({ξ \cdot λ \over 2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Prove that $$\sum_{j=-N}^N e^{i \cdot j \cdot ξ \cdot λ}={\sin(N+{1\over 2}) \cdot (ξ \cdot λ)\over \sin({ξ \cdot λ \over 2})}$$ i think about sum of geometric series but if my thinking is correct how i can do it?

Comment: The $\xi\cdot\lambda$ in the numerator is inside of $\sin$?

Comment: no it is not is a product to sin

Comment: I don't think that is correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify, let $\xi\cdot\lambda=x$.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=-N}^Ne^ij & x=e^{-iNx}{1-e^{2iNx}\over 1-e^{ix}}=e^{-iNx}{e^{i(N+1/2)x}\over e^{ix/2}}{e^{-i(N+1/2)x}-e^{i(N+1/2)x}\over e^{-ix/2}-e^{ix/2}}\\
& ={\sin((N+1/2)x)\over sin (x/2)}.
\end{align}$$